# how to use getCountryFromIP PHP function to know users location and display button based on it?

Tags: php, geolocation

I have a PHP function

```
<?php
    function getCountryFromIP($ip, $type = "code"){
        $details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}"));
        $details = get_object_vars($details);
        $country = $details["country"];
        return $country;
    }
?>
```

Now I want to use this function to get the users location and based on that location display a specific button which will take the user to a corresponding PDF based on his location.

In my html i have this,

```
<div class="locbuttons">
    <a class="btn btn-large trial-button" href="/ebooks/EUConsultantsPack.pdf" target="_blank"><button>Consultant's Pack</button></a>
    <a class="btn btn-large trial-button" href="/ebooks/USConsultantsPack.pdf" target="_blank"><button>Consultant's Pack</button></a>
</div>
```

Comment: http://blackbe.lt/advanced-method-to-obtain-the-client-ip-in-php/  . Now pass this ip to your function and get the country name and based on that use condition to show specific button

Comment: So what is the problem, it should be quite simple to replace the 2 character country code in the `href="/ebooks/USConsultantsPack.pdf"` assuming the HTML is built by some PHP code. Of course `EU` does not match a country code or one specific language, but I assume this is just example code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes your function for getting the country works..

You're probably going to have to use an Array and match up the country (in your array) with the ebook.

```
<?php
$dataArray = array(
array("Country" =>"United Kingdom", "pdf" => "/ebooks/EUConsultantsPack.pdf"),
array("Country" => "Germany", "pdf" => "/ebooks/EUConsultantsPack.pdf"),
array("Country" => "United States of America", "pdf" => "/ebooks/USConsultantsPack.pdf")
);
?>
```

And then, once you call your function and retrieve the users country....

```
<?php
$country = getCountryFromIP($ip);
foreach($dataArray as $dA){
  if ($country == $dA['Country']){
  //if the country matches our array, we can print out the correct button
     echo '<a class="btn btn-large trial-button" href="'.$dA['pdf'].'" target="_blank"><button>Consultant\'s Pack</button></a>';
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Slight over kill. All he needs/wants to do is replace a 2 char country code in the `href`. Also as that function returns a 2 character country code your array is not much use to OP

Comment: @RiggsFolly The page he's using to query the IP address doesn't output a 2 char country code for "europe" which he need

Comment: Correct, however Europe does not speak one language either, So I have to assume that was just a badly thought out example

Comment: I agree to what you say, but I have to assume he has one ebook for all of Europe (given the example).

Comment: So we are both assuming. Ouch! A dangerous habit for both of us to get into. But anyway, your array does not convert `GB`, `FR`, `IT` etc to anything and those are the `country` code formats returned by that function

Comment: Good spot! OP take note that you'll have to change the country to the country code